# It is possible to get single polygon using gdal.Polygonize()?

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, polygonize

I have to get polygon outline for all raster in our server. I tried one example raster  and used gdal.Polygonize() function. With that I could produce thousands of small polygons but I only want a big polygon showing raster data areas. Does anyone have any idea How could I do this?

My Code sample:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import sys
# this allows GDAL to throw Python Exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

#  get raster datasource

src_ds = gdal.Open( r"F:\Geodaten\Eigene\Luftbild\Orthobilder\20130802\Klostermoor2013_Ortho-0-0.jpg" )
print src_ds 
if src_ds is None:
    print 'Unable to open %s' % src_filename
    sys.exit(1)
print "Done"

srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(3)
print srcband 

# create output datasource

dst_layername =r"F:\TRANSFER (RW)\Shiuli\script_andre\raster_luftbild\POLYGONIZED_STUFF"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

if os.path.exists(dst_layername+".shp"):
    drv.DeleteDataSource(dst_layername+".shp")
    print 'deleted'
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )
#prog_func = gdal.TermProgress

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
dst_ds.Destroy()
src_ds=None
print "we are done..."
```

Here is the snapshot of my results:
[image: comparative view of raster and outpolygons in shapefile]

Comment: Gdal_polygonize combines pixels with same values into polygons. For getting the result that you wish with gdal_polygonize you must pre-process your data and update all non-nodata pixels to have some common value. I believe you could do that with gdal_calc.py.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1):

> The algorithm will generally produce very dense polygon geometries,
>   with edges that follow exactly on pixel boundaries for all
>   non-interior pixels. For non-thematic raster data (such as satellite
>   images) the result will essentially be one small polygon per pixel,
>   and memory and output layer sizes will be substantial. The algorithm
>   is primarily intended for relatively simple thematic imagery, masks,
>   and classification results.

If you convert your input image to a 0 (nodata) & 1 (data) only raster with either numpy/QGIS Raster Calculator/or gdal_calc.py (i.e `gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=tmp.tif --calc="A>0"`) you can use something like:

```
gdal.Polygonize( srcband, srcband, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

Note use of `srcband` as the mask band (2nd argument).

Comment: it worked better but it is still providing thousands of polygon in data areas. I wanted to have a big polygon at the end